# How does the view in backbone marionette know which model is associated with it?

Tags: marionette

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md

In this example:

```
<script id="my-template" type="text/html">
  I think that <%= showMessage() %>
</script> 

MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#my-template",

  templateHelpers: {
    showMessage: function(){
      return this.name + " is the coolest!"
    }
  }

});

model = new Backbone.Model({name: "Backbone.Marionette"});
view = new MyView();
view.render(); //=> "I think that Backbone.Marionette is the coolest!";
```

I've tried analyzing this code and based on my understanding of Backbone, you have to specify which model the view is associated with. I tried understanding Marionette views and I don't know which part of the docs or in this example shows how the view knew that `this` refers to the newly created model. Or is this just a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an error in that example. It should show this:

```
model = new Backbone.Model({name: "Backbone.Marionette"});

view = new MyView({
  model: model
});

view.render(); //=> "I think that Backbone.Marionette is the coolest!";
```

I'll update the docs to fix this

Comment: ah i was hoping it was that. if it wasn't i'd be really confused. thanks for the quick reply!